# linux: redirect stdout after the process started

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, stdout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a process intercept stdout and stderr of another process on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249703/how-can-a-process-intercept-stdout-and-stderr-of-another-process-on-linux)

I have a process that already started, with stdout to the console.
can I redirect it to a file, without restarting it?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249703/how-can-a-process-intercept-stdout-and-stderr-of-another-process-on-linux