# How to redirect output of an already running process

Tags: linux, bash

Normally I would start a command like

```
longcommand &;
```

I know you can redirect it by doing something like

```
longcommand > /dev/null;
```

for instance to get rid of the output or

```
longcommand 2>&1 > output.log
```

to capture output.

But I sometimes forget, and was wondering if there is a way to capture or redirect after the fact.

```
longcommand
ctrl-z
bg 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

or something like that so I can continue using the terminal without messages popping up on the terminal.

Comment: SO is probably not optimal for this questions. I'm guessing SU is best, though the SF might have a better chance of answering it. MY best understanding, BTW: try `disown` if that fails you are out of luck.

Comment: You probably mean > where you wrote |. Both sides of a pipe have to be executables. If you're redirecting to a file or device (such as /dev/null) you use > and <.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249703/how-can-a-process-intercept-stdout-and-stderr-of-another-process-on-linux http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682783/linux-redirect-stdout-after-the-process-started

Comment: [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr)

Comment: i know it's a workaround but you can also do `shopt huponexit` logout and login,

Answer (score 165, accepted):

See **[Redirecting Output from a Running Process](http://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/)**.

> Firstly I run the command `cat > foo1` in one session and test that data from stdin is copied to the file. Then in another session I redirect the output.
>
> Firstly find the PID of the process:
>
> ```
> $ ps aux | grep cat
> rjc 6760 0.0 0.0 1580 376 pts/5 S+ 15:31 0:00 cat
> ```
>
> Now check the file handles it has open:
>
> ```
> $ ls -l /proc/6760/fd
> total 3
> lrwx—— 1 rjc rjc 64 Feb 27 15:32 0 -> /dev/pts/5
> l-wx—— 1 rjc rjc 64 Feb 27 15:32 1 -> /tmp/foo1
> lrwx—— 1 rjc rjc 64 Feb 27 15:32 2 -> /dev/pts/5
> ```
>
> Now run GDB:
>
> ```
> $ gdb -p 6760 /bin/cat
> GNU gdb 6.4.90-debian
>
> [license stuff snipped]
>
> Attaching to program: /bin/cat, process 6760
>
> [snip other stuff that's not interesting now]
>
> (gdb) p close(1)
> $1 = 0
> (gdb) p creat("/tmp/foo3", 0600)
> $2 = 1
> (gdb) q
> The program is running. Quit anyway (and detach it)? (y or n) y
> Detaching from program: /bin/cat, process 6760
> ```
>
> The `p` command in GDB will print the value of an expression, an expression can be a function to call, it can be a system call… So I execute a `close()` system call and pass file handle 1, then I execute a `creat()` system call to open a new file. The result of the `creat()` was 1 which means that it replaced the previous file handle. If I wanted to use the same file for stdout and stderr or if I wanted to replace a file handle with some other number then I would need to call the `dup2()` system call to achieve that result.
>
> For this example I chose to use `creat()` instead of `open()` because there are fewer parameter. The C macros for the flags are not usable from GDB (it doesn’t use C headers) so I would have to read header files to discover this – it’s not that hard to do so but would take more time. Note that 0600 is the octal permission for the owner having read/write access and the group and others having no access. It would also work to use 0 for that parameter and run chmod on the file later on.
>
> After that I verify the result:
>
> ```
> ls -l /proc/6760/fd/
> total 3
> lrwx—— 1 rjc rjc 64 2008-02-27 15:32 0 -> /dev/pts/5
> l-wx—— 1 rjc rjc 64 2008-02-27 15:32 1 -> /tmp/foo3 <====
> lrwx—— 1 rjc rjc 64 2008-02-27 15:32 2 -> /dev/pts/5
> ```
>
> Typing more data in to `cat` results in the file `/tmp/foo3` being appended to.
>
> If you want to close the original session you need to close all file handles for it, open a new device that can be the controlling tty, and then call `setsid()`.

Comment: Always better to copy the gist of it here rather than just linking.

Comment: The gist: attach to the running process using `gdb`, then do 'p close(1)' and 'p creat("/tmp/foo3", 0600)' to redirect STDOUT, then disconnect gdb while leaving the program running.  A clever trick!

Comment: If i could have gave you an Up Vote for every time i have used that link from your post, you would've been in the top 100 at least. By the way don't you feel the urge to get out of the userXXX league?

Comment: This solution works, but I had to use gdb as root or the process failed to attach.

Comment: Why would you link to such a trashy website filled with advertisers?  It's obvious that the answer to this question did not originate from this site.  Damn, backlink spammers.  I hope someone teaches them a lesson. Maybe that person  is me?

Comment: Usually a good way to get the header file constants in C is through python. For example: `import os; print(os.O_RDRW)`

Comment: how does `creat` call know that it has to overwrite file handle `1` i.e. `stdout` ?

Comment: @iggy I guess it just uses the first free handle (and `1` was just closed, so obviously free and also first).

Comment: The nice thing is that this works also on cygwin :D

Comment: Tried this with `python` code and got error regarding return type: `'close' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type`
Fixed it by adding `(int)` in front of called functions, like `p (int)close(1)`

Comment: Similarly, one can also use the dup2 function in combination with open to replace the file descriptor `(gdb) p dup2(open("/tmp/process_stdout", 1089, 0777), 1)` ( from https://www.baeldung.com/linux/redirect-output-of-running-process )

Answer (score 30):

You can also do it using `reredirect` (https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect/).

The command bellow redirects the outputs (standard and error) of the process `PID` to `FILE`:

```
reredirect -m FILE PID
```

The `README` of `reredirect` also explains other interesting features: how to restore the original state of the process, how to redirect to another command or to redirect only stdout or stderr.

The tool also provides `relink`, a script allowing to redirect the outputs to the current terminal:

```
relink PID
relink PID | grep usefull_content
```

(`reredirect` seems to have same features than Dupx described in another answer but, it does not depend on Gdb).

Comment: Neat thing about reredirect, it also lets you restore state afterwards once you're done.

Comment: Note that the FILE should not exist before running the above command or else reredirect hangs. Otherwise it's a very useful program.

Comment: Any idea how to redirect without upsetting the process's current output to terminal?

Answer (score 16):

> ## Dupx
>
> Dupx is a simple *nix utility to redirect standard output/input/error of an already running process.
>
> ### Motivation
>
> I've often found myself in a situation where a process I started on a remote system via SSH takes much longer than I had anticipated. I need to break the SSH connection, but if I do so, the process will die if it tries to write something on stdout/error of a broken pipe. I wish I could suspend the process with ^Z and then do a
>
> ```
> bg %1 >/tmp/stdout 2>/tmp/stderr
> ```
>
> Unfortunately this will not work (in shells I know).

[http://www.isi.edu/~yuri/dupx/](http://www.isi.edu/%7Eyuri/dupx/)

Answer (score 12):

**Screen**

If process is running in a screen session you can use screen's log command to log the output of that window to a file:

Switch to the script's window, <kbd>C-a</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> to log.
Now you can :

```
$ tail -f screenlog.2 | grep whatever
```

From screen's man page:

> log [on|off]
>
> Start/stop writing output of the current window to a file "screenlog.n" in the window's default directory, where n is the number of the current window. This filename can be changed with the 'logfile' command. If no parameter is given, the state of logging is toggled. The session log is appended to the previous contents of the file if it already exists. The current contents and the contents of the scrollback history are not included in the session log. Default is 'off'.

I'm sure tmux has something similar as well.

Answer (score 1):

I collected some information on the internet and prepared the script that requires no external tool: [See my response here](https://superuser.com/a/535938/189823). Hope it's helpful.