# linux terminal that is currently running and logging to stdout. how do you silence its output?

Tags: linux, unix, command

I have a console that is printing to stdout.

How do i get access to the command prompt and silence the output to stdout ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see console output, don't log in to a console.  If you are getting log messages written to a device that is not supposed to be a console, then your system is set up wrong.  You need to change the kernel command line at boot which can set the console device.

Most likely you have a system with no GUI which is logging to the main display as its console.  In that case you can change the message severity in /etc/rsyslog.conf from kern.* (the default) to kern.err.  You might also consider fixing the broken program that is logging so many messages.

Comment: I am talking from the perspective of a developer. Let say you are compiling a large application and it going to take 1 hour.Meantime you want to do some other work ..... but you do not want to open another console.... how do you quiten the output to stdout.

Comment: @user780803 - Use [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of alternatives:

- Use your shell redirection and process control operators to send both the standard output and standard error of a command to a file, while also launching it in the background:

  For example in `bash`:

  ```
  make all 1>make.log 2>&1 &
  ```

  Even better you can use a separate file for each stream:

  ```
  make all 1>make.out 2>make.err &
  ```

  The command is launched in the background and the shell will let you know when it is finished. In the mean time you can use a text viewer or even just `tail` on the output files to see what is going on.

  If error messages are rare and you want to see them immediately, you could only redirect the standard output:

  ```
  make all 1>make.log &
  ```

  If you do not care about the console messages at all, just send them to `/dev/null`:

  ```
  make all 1>/dev/null &
  ```
- If your concern about new consoles is the login procedure, you can use a tool such as [`GNU screen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) or [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) to create additional console windows within your current session.
- If you want to gain access to the console where a process has already been started, you need first to stop it with the appropriate keyboard shortcut, then let it continue in the background. For example in Linux/`bash` with the `Ctrl+Z` shortcut:

  ```
  $ make all
  1/10
  2/10
  ^Z
  [1]+  Stopped                 make all
  $ bg
  [1]+ make all &
  3/10
  $ 4/10
  5/10
  6/10
  7/10
  8/10
  9/10
  10/10

  [1]+  Done                    make all
  $
  ```

  Unfortunately, [there is no easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1323956/507519) to redirect/quiet the output of a process that is already running - the messages will still be flooding the console.

  Of course if you only need short-term access to the console (e.g. to check an output file), you can just *not* restart the process until after you are done:

  ```
  $ make all
  1/10
  2/10
  ^Z
  [1]+  Stopped                 make all
  $ ls
  1  2  Makefile
  $ fg
  make all
  3/10
  4/10
  5/10
  6/10
  7/10
  8/10
  9/10
  10/10
  $
  ```

  For more information on the `bg` and `fg` job control builtin commands of `bash`, have a look [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#Job-Control-Builtins).

Comment: Thank you I was referring to your third scenario. I thought it might be  possible.

Comment: @user780803: it seems that it *is* possible - as long as you do not mind your application being poked at with `gdb`. I think I would exhaust all other alternatives first, including interrupting the application, before going for the equivalent of performing brain surgery while blind-folded and riding on a horse...