# Linux access stout of a program already running

Tags: linux, process

At a console, is it possible to get stdout to print from a process that is already running in the background, via say it's process id?

Comment: you will need to acquire the process handle at startup...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323999/1203773)

There is just a link to this tutorial: http://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/