# How to take back process from init (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, init

I wrote simple script -  endless loop, after it i start script with "&" and close terminal window. I was killed parent process and "init" took it. 
How can i give back process from "init"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The process was inherited by init because its parent process has died. You cannot change process's parent in any other way. However, this is hardly an issue in itself becuase init takes (foster) care of the process. If you only need to redirect the process's output, [there is already StackOverflow question on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process).