# ipython notebook logging to notebook

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm playing with spark in ipython notebook and having a blast, but unfortunately a recent change (maybe a recent spark upgrade) caused spark logging to the notebook rather than the console where I started the notebook. I still want to see these log messages so I can't just turn off logging, but I would prefer it be directed to console rather than logging to the notebook. Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your conf/log4j.properties file and Change the following line:

```
   log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
```

to

```
    log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console
```

Another approach would be to :

Fireup spark-shell and type in the following:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

You won't see any logs after that.

(copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323999/348056)