# Bash: Silence a process put into background

Tags: bash, background, stdout, dev-null

If I run a application using the bash and I put it into the background via

- `STRG+z`
- `bg` command

If now the process is printing to `stdout` the shell prints this output. This output is not interesting for me and I do not like my shell to be polluted with it.

Is there a way to redirect the output form this process to `/dev/null`

I could have achieved the very same by directly starting the application in background with `(./application &> /dev/null)&`, but my application is already running and I would not like to quit it and restart it.

Comment: Then what is not working? Your idea seems good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is:

1. Bringing the job to the foreground (see [Job control](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html)).
2. Redirecting ouput (see below).
3. Sending to the backgrouond again.

[How to redirect output of an already running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process)

https://superuser.com/questions/473240/redirect-stdout-while-a-process-is-running-what-is-that-process-sending-to-d

[Redirect STDERR / STDOUT of a process AFTER it's been started, using command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin)

https://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/