# How to do a tail -f on node process.stdout?

Tags: node.js

Im not a node developer by nature and I have this project and I am trying to debug something. And I notice that the logger is logging to process.stdout .... How can I tail -f this in a running node server?

Comment: `node server | tee your-log.txt&; tail -f your-log.txt`

Comment: ? ... i dont understand that

Comment: If you control how to start node, you can redirect the output `process.stdout` into a file via the command line, then do the `tail -f` on it

Comment: Thats not an option... there is no way to see it without doing that?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process/1323999#1323999

Comment: if your are in a *ix system, this probably the best: `strace -ewrite -p $PID`

Answer (score 0):

### Option #1 - Most common

Just run your script/server like this:

```
node ./my-server.js >/path/to/logs/my-server.log 2>&1
```

Then to tail ...

```
tail -f /path/to/logs/my-server.log
```

NB.: For production, you might want to use something like [logrotate](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/rotating-logs-logrotate) in addition.

### Option #2 - For hackers

Wherever you are using `process.stdout.write(msg)` or `console.log(msg)`, you can  use `process.emit('logger#receiver-id', JSON.stringify({content: msg}))`

```js
// sample.js
function doSomething() {
  // console.log('Hello world');
  var msg = 'Hello World !';
  process.emit('logger#catch-all', JSON.stringify({content: msg}))
}
doSomething();
```

```js
// tail.js
function onPayload(payload) {
  var msg = JSON.parse(payload).content;
  process.stdout.write(msg);
}

function registerEvent() {
  process.on('logger#catch-all', onPayload);
}
registerEvent();
```

Then you can now get your logs by running (first) `tail.js`, then `sample.js`

This method is just a sample of what you can do by considering logs as events ... You can then write your own containers and format payloads depending on where your logs are going: stdout, file, monitoring tools ...

You might have to override `console.<method>()` if you do not want to use directly `process.emit(...)`.