# How to bring a running background process to foreground?

Tags: server, terminal, stdout

I have a process running on the server, for some reason my client system got restarted so i login again to the server using a terminal.

The process is running as expected but the status of the process which is continously promted on the terminal disappear for obvious reason (because i am on another terminal now).

Is there any way so that i can bring the STDOUT of my running process to the current terminal ?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect output of an already running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process)

Answer (score 0):

See **[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323999/820410)**.

> Firstly I run the command `cat > foo1` in one session and test that data from stdin is copied to the file. Then in another session I redirect the output.
>
> Firstly find the PID of the process:
>
> ```
> $ ps aux | grep cat
> rjc 6760 0.0 0.0 1580 376 pts/5 S+ 15:31 0:00 cat
> ```
>
> Now check the file handles it has open:
>
> ```
> $ ls -l /proc/6760/fd
> total 3
> lrwx—— 1 rjc rjc 64 Feb 27 15:32 0 -> /dev/pts/5
> l-wx—— 1 rjc rjc 64 Feb 27 15:32 1 -> /tmp/foo1
> lrwx—— 1 rjc rjc 64 Feb 27 15:32 2 -> /dev/pts/5
> ```
>
> Now run GDB:
>
> ```
> $ gdb -p 6760 /bin/cat
> GNU gdb 6.4.90-debian
>
> [license stuff snipped]
>
> Attaching to program: /bin/cat, process 6760
>
> [snip other stuff that's not interesting now]
>
> (gdb) p close(1)
> $1 = 0
> (gdb) p creat("/tmp/foo3", 0600)
> $2 = 1
> (gdb) q
> The program is running. Quit anyway (and detach it)? (y or n) y
> Detaching from program: /bin/cat, process 6760
> ```
>
> The `p` command in GDB will print the value of an expression, an expression can be a function to call, it can be a system call… So I execute a `close()` system call and pass file handle 1, then I execute a `creat()` system call to open a new file. The result of the `creat()` was 1 which means that it replaced the previous file handle. If I wanted to use the same file for stdout and stderr or if I wanted to replace a file handle with some other number then I would need to call the `dup2()` system call to achieve that result.
>
> For this example I chose to use `creat()` instead of `open()` because there are fewer parameter. The C macros for the flags are not usable from GDB (it doesn’t use C headers) so I would have to read header files to discover this – it’s not that hard to do so but would take more time. Note that 0600 is the octal permission for the owner having read/write access and the group and others having no access. It would also work to use 0 for that parameter and run chmod on the file later on.
>
> After that I verify the result:
>
> ```
> ls -l /proc/6760/fd/
> total 3
> lrwx—— 1 rjc rjc 64 2008-02-27 15:32 0 -> /dev/pts/5
> l-wx—— 1 rjc rjc 64 2008-02-27 15:32 1 -> /tmp/foo3 <====
> lrwx—— 1 rjc rjc 64 2008-02-27 15:32 2 -> /dev/pts/5
> ```
>
> Typing more data in to `cat` results in the file `/tmp/foo3` being appended to.
>
> If you want to close the original session you need to close all file handles for it, open a new device that can be the controlling tty, and then call `setsid()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use following script to change std out of any process.

This script attaches gdb and change file descriptor of process, detaches gdb and process continues.

Usage: <script_path> <process_id> <optional: output file>

If output file is not specified, output is redirected to current terminal

```
#!/bin/sh

filename=`tty`
if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    filename=`tty`
else
    file_abs_path=`echo $2 | grep "^/.*"`
    if [ -z "$file_abs_path" ]; then
        filename="`pwd`/$2"
    else
        filename=$2
    fi
fi

original_terminal=`file /proc/$1/fd/1 | grep -o "symbolic.*" | grep -o "\/[^ ']*"`
echo "Original stdout: $original_terminal"
echo "" > $1.temp
echo "p fileno(fopen("\"$filename\"", "\""w"\""))" >> $1.temp
echo 'call dup2($1, 1)' >> $1.temp
echo 'call dup2($1, 2)' >> $1.temp
echo "q" >> $1.temp


gdb -p $1  -x $1.temp < /dev/null >& /dev/null
echo "New stdout: $filename"
rm -rf $1.temp
```