# Detach from named pipe without terminating source program

Tags: shell, pipe, ipc, wireshark

Given two programs A and B.
A produces output.
B consumes input.
On Linux you can connect them with `A | B`.

Alternatively, if I want to split the execution of those programs, i can use a named pipe:

```
mkfifo pipe
A > pipe &
B < pipe &
```

However if I terminate B, A gets also killed.

Is there a way to connect A to B, while restarting B multiple times?
It is not important that B loses data (e.g. during being killed in the following example), while not running.
Following would be my goal, but it does not work:

```
mkfifo pipe
A > pipe &
B > pipe &
kill B
B > pipe &
```

Why do I need this?

In my case A is the JSON output from Wireshark and i am developing B to parse the correct data.
I would like to do it interactively but for that i need Wireshark (or `tshark`) to continue sending data.

I am aware of possible duplicates with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process), however my question is different. I did not forget to redirect A to somewhere else, I can prepare it beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` receives a `SIGPIPE` the moment `B` terminates. A workaround is:

```
exec 3<>pipe
A >&3 &
B <&3 &
```

This way the kernel won't signal `A` when `B` dies as the fifo was opened for reading by another process; i.e `B` wasn't the last process reading from it.

Comment: Remark: Works in bash. It has to be in the same shell.