# How to capture the stdout of a running process which already has redirected it to /dev/null

Tags: linux, stdout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a process intercept stdout and stderr of another process on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249703/how-can-a-process-intercept-stdout-and-stderr-of-another-process-on-linux)

The process is already running and has all 0, 1, 2 redirected to /dev/null, how can I restore the stdout?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing ...

Possibility 1: you want to capture output that was redirected. You're out of luck.
Possibility 2: you want to capture output that will be redirected. Debug inject and call dup2.
Possibility 3: you are the process. Maybe try /dev/tty

.