# How can I listen to a running Linux process?

Tags: ruby, linux, process

I was running a rake task as a separate process in my server and printing on STDOUT tracking the progress of that script.

While in the SSH connection, my internet connection reset. When I reestablished the connection to the server, I found that the process was still running. I want to listen to its STDOUT ouput. I have the process id.

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you should really use tmux or screen for this kind of stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a process intercept stdout and stderr of another process on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249703/how-can-a-process-intercept-stdout-and-stderr-of-another-process-on-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the future, consider [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).  This wonderful little tool can hold a large number of virtual terminals and let you easily switch from one to the next (without even using the mouse), but what's best, is if you get disconnected the virtual terminals live on until you reconnect and recover the screen session.

To start a screen session:

```
screen
```

To detach a screen session on purpose so you can disconnect and leave it running:

```
C-a C-d
```

To reattach your detached screen session

```
screen -dr
```

There's a whole lot more to it, but that's enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

`retty` should do what you want.  http://pasky.or.cz/dev/retty/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Linux VM handy to test this on, but you might be able to connect to the process with gdb, `open(2)` a new file descriptor to use as standard output, then `dup2(2)` that to fd 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
strace  -p $pid_of_process_you_want_to_see_stdout_of 2>&1| sed -re 's%^write\(1,[[:blank:]](.*),[[:blank:]]*[0-9]+\)[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[0-9]+%\1%g'
```

Stolen from here:

https://superuser.com/questions/473240/redirect-stdout-while-a-process-is-running-what-is-that-process-sending-to-d