# Read stdout from a process (linux embedded)

Tags: linux, stdout, busybox

Before flagging the question as duplicate, please read my various issues I encountered.

A bit of background: we are developing a C++ application running on embedded ARM sbc using a lite variant of debian linux. The application start at boot launched by the boot script and print various information to stdout. What we would like is the ability to connect using SSH/Telnet and read the application output, without having to kill the process and restart it for the current bash session. I want to create a simple .sh script for non-tech-savvy people to use.

The first solution for the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249703/how-can-a-process-intercept-stdout-and-stderr-of-another-process-on-linux) posted here is to use gdb. First it's not user-friendly (need to write multiple commands manually) and I wonder why but it don't seems to output anything into the file.

The second solution `strace -ewrite -p PID` works perfectly, that's what I want. Problem is, there's a lot more information than just the stdout, and it's badly formatted.

I managed to get an "acceptable" result with `strace -e write=1 -s 1024 -p 20049 2>&1 | grep "write(1,"` but it still have the superfluous `write(1, "...", 19)    = 19` text. Up to this point it's simply a bit of string formatting, and I've found on multiple other pages this line saying it achieve good formatting : `strace -ff -e write=1,2 -s 1024 -p PID 2>&1 | grep "^ |" | cut -c11-60 | sed -e 's/ //g' | xxd -r -p`

There are some things I find strange in this command (why -ff?, why grep "^ |"?, why use xxd there?) and it just don't output anything when I try it.

Unfortunately, we do use a old buggy version of busybox (1.7.1) that have some problem with multiple pipes. That bug gives me bad results. For example, if I only do grep it works, and if I only do cut it also works, but let's say "grep "write(1," | cut -c11-60" returns nothing.

I know the real solution would simply be to update busybox and use these multiple pipes to format the string, but we can't update it since the os distribution is already installed on thousands of boards shipped to our clients worldwide..

Anyone have a miraculous solution? Thanks

Comment: Does your "lite" Linux come with the program "screen" or can you build screen for it?

Comment: Screen is not present, but could probably be built easily. Seems like it could work great, but I don't like the fact that unlike strace, screen must be the parent process of your application and can't just connect to an already running one.

Answer (score 0):

Screen can be connected to an existing process using reptyr (http://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/), or you can use neercs (http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/neercs) which I haven't used but apparently is like screen but supports attaching to an existing process all by itself.