# centos capture the output from the java background process

Tags: java, centos

I am running a java process in the background. It prints out the log through system.out. It is supposed to run for a long time, so I can't stop it now. It is running on the CentOS 6.

Is there a command to capture the output from a java process running in the background?

thanks.

Comment: When you start it, you can redirect the output to a file then tail that file. If you've already started it and can't restart it, I don't know a way to change the output pipe

Comment: I forgot adding a pipe..  I can't stop it now, because it's supposed to run for a long time. If I stop, I have to start from the beginning.

Comment: Suggest you try asking on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ (or maybe http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter that it's Java, the problem is just to capture the stdout of a running process in Linux, and a quick search produces this: [How can a process intercept stdout and stderr of another process on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249703/how-can-a-process-intercept-stdout-and-stderr-of-another-process-on-linux).